# How to get logged in camunda user information in my ejb?

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, camunda

I am working with Camunda BPM in Camunda Glassfish Distribution (JAVA EE) for process automation.
I want to get currently logged in user information in my ejb.

I tried to get it as per the following code:

```
    @Inject
    IdentityService identityService;

    public void persist(DelegateExecution delegateExecution) {

        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "User Id: " +     identityService.getCurrentAuthentication().getUserId());
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

and I get a null pointer exception. Is there any other way to get the user Id or current authentication?

Comment: In what context do you use the code? Who is calling "persist" and how do you access the delegateExecution?   If this is executed by a async service task or after an event, you have no logged in user ...

Comment: Hi @JanGalinski,

Actually there was some confusion, there are other code segments represented by the dots, where there are some inputs and we set those inputs using process variables in our entity. Persist method is invoked after we try to save the inputs from the form.